# MPI_Sendrecv deadlock

Tags: mpi, deadlock

Could anyone help me to fix the bug in the following simple MPI prog. I was trying to use MPI_Sendrecv to send the "c" value from rank 1 to 2, and they print it from rank 2. 
But, the following code ends with a deadlock. 
What is the mistake, how to correctly use MPI_Sendrecv (in this situation)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"mpi.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        int size, rank;
        MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
        printf("Hi dear, I am printing from rank %d\n",rank);

        double a, b, c;
        MPI_Status status, status2;

        if (rank == 0)
        {
                a = 10.1;
                MPI_Send(&a,1,MPI_DOUBLE,1,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        if (rank == 1)
        {
                b = 20.1;
                MPI_Recv(&a,1,MPI_DOUBLE,0,99,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                c = a + b;
                printf("\nThe value of c is %f \n",c);
        }
        MPI_Sendrecv(&c,1,MPI_DOUBLE,2,100,
                     &c,1,MPI_DOUBLE,1,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);

        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if(rank == 2)
        {
               printf("\n Printing from rank %d, c is %f\n",rank, c);
        }


        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When a process calls MPI_Sendrecv, it will *always* try to execute *both* the send and receive part.  For instance, if it is process 2, it will *not* look at the `dest` (fourth argument), see a "2" and think, "Oh, I don't have to do any sending.  I'll just do the receive."  nstead, process 2 will see the "2" and think, "Ah, I have to send something to myself."  Further, as you have written this code, *all* processes see the `MPI_SendRecv` and think, "Oh.  I have to send something to process 2 (the fourth argument) and receive something from process 1 (the ninth argument).  So here we go ..."  The problem is that process 1 isn't getting a command to send anything, so everyone, even process 1, is waiting for process 1 to send something.

`MPI_Sendrecv` is a very useful function.  I find uses for it all the time.  But it is intended for sending in a "chain".  For instance, 0 sends to 1 *while* 1 sends to 2 *while* 2 sends to 0 or whatever.  I think in this case you are better off with the usual MPI_Send and MPI_Recv.